# How do I link Vscode console to a separate cmd or powershell so when I run commands I get the results back in a separate window

Tags: powershell, cmd, terminal, visual-studio-code

I am web scraping and want a separate window to view the code as there is so much information for me to look at. It is very annoying to keep maximizing the console to view everything. What is the best practice to do this? Ideally I would want to press the green icon (run code in terminal) but have the output in a separate windowed terminal.

Comment: We are here to help with PowerShell code issues, so this is really off-topic since you are asking about and environment setup. So, really a SuperUser post, so move it there. Yet, since you are here.  Use a verticle pin. Code window on one side and console on the other. If you have a multi-monitor setup, then just stretch VSCode so that the Editor is on one and the console is on the other. See the options in the View Menu. That has been my setup (4 monitors these days) since day one for dev/scripting tools that allow it.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment...

User Interface
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface

[image]

Run the code in the editor, let the console deal with the response. You can have multiple terminals in the console pane of course.

[image]

Sending results from one terminal to another is not something I've tried or even seen done. Nothing in the docs allude to that.